# Running API on Windows Server - Python

Tags: python, api, windows-server-2008

I have written an API using python(Flask Microframework). To run this API I open the Command Prompt navigate to API folder and run the "run.py" python file using following command:

```
python [filename].py
```

Post which I get a message saying *"Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/"*
Hence I am able to access data using the following URL

```
localhost:5000/[API call]
```

My question is if I put all this set up in Windows Server(which would involve installing Python and necessary Libraries) and run the "run.py" python file, will I be able to access the API from any other machine as per below URL

```
[Server IP Address]:5000/[API call]
```

The way I'm able to access the API using localhost in my machine, will I be able to access the API by replacing the localhost with the server IP Address.

Answer (score 2):

No, this won't work without a change. If you're listening on 127.0.0.1, only clients on the same machine (localhost, 127.0.0.1) can connect to you. You need to listen on 0.0.0.0.

This is thoroughly explained in the Flask [Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/) docs:

> Externally Visible Server
>
> If you run the server you will notice that the server is only accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network. This is the default because in debugging mode a user of the application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
>
> If you have debug disabled or trust the users on your network, you can make the server publicly available simply by changing the call of the `run()` method to look like this:
>
> `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`
>
> This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.

Then, you will see `Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/`, and you will be able to connect to it from other machines by using the server's IP address. (Assuming they're on reachable networks and there are no firewalls in the way and so forth, of course…)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in production mode (or something like that) **don't** run it with command line because this only must be used for development. Use the methods recomended in the oficial [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/) to deploy your app.

Answer (score 0):

The below tutorial is very helpful
https://claudiosparpaglione.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/how-to-deploy-flask-applications-to-apache-webserver/

Answer (score 0):

Just add python.exe to your windows defender firewall.
Choose 0.0.0.0 as Flask app.run host to listen to all addresses. It will automatically select your VPS IP address